# Need help to align element in Grid Gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need help for grid, green is grid and black is the grid gap. How I can align colon in gap?
I tried with flex and grid but nothing working out.

[image]

Result are like :
[image]

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML and CSS in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You should be able to do this with pseudo elements as the colons aren't really part of the actual data, only a visual clue, but we don't know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colons are a visual clue rather than an integral part of the data.

This means they can be added using pseudo elements.

In this snippet each of the numbers is in a div which has an after pseudo element which is given the same width as the grid gap. It is positioned after the number's div so is placed exactly between two grid items.

Here is a basic example. Obviously you will want to alter the sizes and colors to suit your particular requirements.

```css
.grid {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  --gap: 30px;
  gap: var(--gap);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: black;
}

.grid>* {
  color: white;
  background: teal;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid>* *:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 72px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid>* *:first-child::after {
  content: ':';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: var(--gap);
}

.grid>*:last-child *:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>36</div>
    <div>Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>04</div>
    <div>Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```